# RedisTemplate - hash get multiple entries by key set

Tags: spring, redis

I use spring's RedisTemplate.

I have a hash in redis.

I want to query redis, using the template, in order to get all entries whose key in a certain set of keys.

I noticed the method:

```
Map<Object, Object> entries = redisTemplate.opsForHash().multiGet(HASH_NAME, keySet);
```

But, unfortunately this method returns only the values, without the matching keys.

I could also do it like this:

```
Map<Object, Object> entries = redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(HASH_NAME);
for(Object key : keySet){
    System.out.println(entries.get(key));
}
```

But this means I will get all entries from redis, to my local machine, and iterate them.

Don't I have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget):

> Array reply: list of values associated with the given fields, in the
>   same order as they are requested.

And from the documentation for [Spring Redis Hash multiGet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/HashOperations.html#multiGet%28H,%20java.util.Collection%29), you can see it returns a list (not a map), which should be in the same order as the keys you sent.

Example code:

```
List<Object> values = redisTemplate.opsForHash().multiGet(HASH_NAME, keySet);
int i = 0;
for (String k: keySet) {
    // k is the key
    // and here is the value corresponding to the key k
    Object value = values.get(i++);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using RedisTemplate you could use `opsForHash().entries(H key)` to get all the hash, (keys and values).

For example...

```
Map messageGroupMetadata = redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(H key);
```

Besides it's necesary to set RedisTemplate serializers to complete this operation.

```
redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. Even if the method description says multiget should return the data in the same sequence as input, it does not. It returns it in the way a Map would return. I wanted to open a bug for this but I don't see any option to do so on spring.io.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about spring, but Redis has a native solution for this need.
You can use [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command:

```
SORT index_set BY nosort get # get *->hash_field1 get *->hash_field2 ...
```

The first `get #` will return the set element, which in your case is the hash key name.

Comment: This is interesting but doesn't address op's question.